# How do I eliminate duplicate requires caused by relative paths?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

When optimizing my require.js project using the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` task, many scripts are required multiple times because of relative paths. Here is a list of dependencies outputted during the build:

```
components/requirejs/require.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./././utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/../../lib/./utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/../../lib/registry.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/../../lib/utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/debug.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././compose.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./advice.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/../../lib/./utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/../../lib/registry.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/../../lib/utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/debug.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./compose.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./registry.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/component.js
```

Notice how `utils.js` is included 7 times:

```
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./././utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/../../lib/utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/./../tools/debug/../../lib/./utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/../../lib/utils.js
.tmp/scripts/../../components/flight/lib/././../tools/debug/../../lib/./utils.js
```

[Flight](https://github.com/twitter/flight) requires `utils.js` in every script in their `lib` with the path of `./util` and sometimes requires other dependencies that then require `./util` again.

[`grunt-contrib-requirejs`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) passes their options directly to [requirejs](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs) which includes a function [`trimDots`](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L225) that is supposed to "[trim] the . and .. from an array of path segments."

Why isn't that taking care of some of the obvious duplicates?

What can I do to eliminate the other duplicates where the relative path equates to the same absolute path?

If the relative paths would normalize to absolute paths, all would be good.

**Update:**

This is how my project is structured:

```
.tmp/scripts/ (where coffeescript is compiled)
app/scripts/ (coffeescript source)
components/ (bower components)
dist/ (where optimized code is output)
Gruntfile.coffee (requirejs config)
```

Here is my requirejs config from my Gruntfile:

```
requirejs:
  dist:
    options:
      baseUrl: '.tmp/scripts'
      # paths relative to baseUrl
      paths:
        requireLib: '../../components/requirejs/require'
      include: 'requireLib'
      optimize: 'uglify2'
      generateSourceMaps: true
      preserveLicenseComments: false
      useStrict: true
      wrap: true
      name: 'main'
      out: 'dist/main.js'
      mainConfigFile: '.tmp/scripts/main.js'
```

Here is what's in `app/scripts/main.coffee`:

```
require.config
  paths:
    # required dependencies
    jquery: '../../components/jquery/jquery'
    es5shim: '../../components/es5-shim/es5-shim'
    es5sham: '../../components/es5-shim/es5-sham'
    # plugins
    text: '../../components/requirejs-text/text'
    pickadate: '../../components/pickadate/source/pickadate.legacy'
  map:
    '*':
      'flight/component': '../../components/flight/lib/component'
  shim:
    '../../components/flight/lib/index':
      deps: ['jquery', 'es5shim', 'es5sham']
    'app':
      deps: ['../../components/flight/lib/index']

require ['app'], (App) ->
  App.initialize()
```

Here is what's in `app/scripts/app.coffee`:

```
define [
  'ui/apple',
  'ui/orange'
], (Apple, Orange) ->
  initialize = ->
    Apple.attachTo document
    Orange.attachTo document
    return

  initialize: initialize
```

Both `app/scripts/ui/apple.coffee` and `app/scripts/ui/orange.coffee` are simply:

```
"use strict"
define ['flight/component'], (defineComponent) ->
  apple = ->
    # stuff
  defineComponent apple
```

Comment: My teammate dug into r.js included in the [requirejs node module](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) and confirmed that they aren't normalizing the paths in a way that would eliminate the duplicates I have. Not sure if this is intended or incorrect. If he can dig further, maybe he can open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I've written a grunt task called grunt-reduce which does a whole bunch of optimizations to your page, including correct resolving and minification of requirejs dependencies.

If you are alright with other optimizations being run as well, maybe you should try it to see if you can run it out of the box: https://github.com/Munter/grunt-reduce

Comment: ditch grunt and leverage webpack... Specifically the `DedupePlugin` will do exactly what you need. https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization

Comment: @Deryck why add such a large bounty on a 3 year old question and not provide any additional information?  Did you encounter a similar issue that you were hoping to solve?  It might be better to pose a new question, since the age of this question is drawing people to suggest newer libraries and/or fixes that aren't even relevant today.

Comment: @Claies true, but I have the rep to spare and the question matched my issue exactly (cept for coffee and Flight but those weren't actually relevant here).  I've stepped into a codebase that doesn't leverage requirejs very well and the resulting build is one 12MB JS file with lots of duplicates used.  I think I'll look into a transition to webpack as suggested before you.  Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Try setting baseUrl in the grunt-contrib-requirejs options:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "path/to/base"
        }
    }
}
```

Documented [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).

Comment: I already have `baseUrl` set to `.tmp/scripts` since that's where my CoffeeScript is compiled to. I updated the question with more detail of my project layout.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things with your code that causes question. I know this question was asked over three years ago so some of these concerns might not have been applicable back then. But I went [back in time](https://github.com/flightjs/flight/tree/e5fc35d9d8d6ae0431be4fd6052ce151bb2c0c66) and looked at the flight code from 3 years ago before answering.

1. Why are you providing `requireLib` to the grunt plugin? You shouldn't need to do that as the grunt plugin should load its own. The result will be two require libs loading, which is just confusing.
2. Shim configurations are meant to be used with [non-AMD modules only](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim), however you are shimming both the "app" and flight "index", which are both AMD modules. I would expect some weird behavior from this.
3. In order to fix #2 and to make your code simpler, you can remove the shim altogether and simply map everything "flight" related:

   ```
   # main.coffee
   require.config
     paths:
       # required dependencies
       jquery: '../../components/jquery/jquery'
       es5shim: '../../components/es5-shim/es5-shim'
       es5sham: '../../components/es5-shim/es5-sham'
       # plugins
       text: '../../components/requirejs-text/text'
       pickadate: '../../components/pickadate/source/pickadate.legacy'
     map
       '*':
         'flight': '../../components/flight/lib'

   require ['jquery', 'es5shim', 'es5sham'], (App) ->
     require ['app'], (App) ->
       App.initialize()

   # app.coffee
   define [
     'flight/index',
     'ui/apple',
     'ui/orange'
   ], (Apple, Orange) ->
     initialize = ->
       Apple.attachTo document
       Orange.attachTo document
       return

     initialize: initialize
   ```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problems, so if you can upload a small zip file with the relevant code that would help a lot.